# Erasing elements of Deque container

Tags: c++, deque

I want to erase the elements of a deque. When you have a deque that contain structs and you want to print the elements from back to front, but you don't want to print elements that have the same struct elements how do you do it?

I have a struct like this:

```
struct New_Array {                    
    array<array<int,4>,4> mytable;       
    int h;
};
```

The deque is filled with elements from a previous procedure.
**You want to print all the elements that are in the deque, but each table you print must have a unique "h"**. Only the first table you find with a specific "h" must be printed, the other tables with the same "h" should not be printed. I think this can be also inplemented with a "find" function.

The value of "h" that we will find starting from the back of the deque will be 0 and it will increase its value towards the front of the deque.

I have tried this:

```
void Find_Solution_Path(deque<New_Array> Mydeque)
{
    while(Mydeque.size()>0)
    {
        New_Array y=Mydeque.back();
        PrintBoard(y);         //this is a function that prints the 4x4 array.
        Mydeque.pop_back();
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<Mydeque.size(); i++)
        {
            New_Array xxx=Mydeque[i];
            if(xxx.h==y.h)
            {
                Mydeque.erase(Mydeque[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have have a problem with indexing in the `for` loop: when you erase the i-th element, you increment `i`, but all the following elements' indices already shift by 1.

Comment: @EitanT The deque doesnt start from 0? It starts from 1?

Comment: No, what I mean is the following: suppose you have a queue of elements {10, 20, 30, 40}, and you erase the element at `i = 1` (second element). Your queue is now {10, 30, 40}. After `i++` you get `i = 2`, meaning that the next element to be evaluated is 40. Element 30 is skipped.

Comment: @EitanT You are right. I suppose I can solve this if I write i-- in the if-statement.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use a deque but a set. If you absolutely need the deque, create a set none the less. Define a < operator with an appropriate criterion < reflecting the uniqueness. You insert each printed element into the set. Before printing you check if the element is already present in the set (find).

HTH, Martin

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [std::unique_copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <deque>

struct New_Array {
    array<array<int,4>,4> mytable;
    int h;
    // unique_copy needs this:
    bool operator==(const New_Array& other) { return h == other.h; }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const New_Array& v)
{
    return out << v.h;
}

int main()
{
    std::deque<New_Array> q;
    New_Array temp;

    // {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}
    temp.h = 1;
    q.push_back(temp);
    q.push_back(temp);
    temp.h = 2;
    q.push_back(temp);
    q.push_back(temp);
    temp.h = 3;
    q.push_back(temp);
    q.push_back(temp);

    unique_copy(q.begin(), q.end(), ostream_iterator<New_Array>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

The range needs to be **sorted** for `unique_copy` to work properly. Sorting isn't needed in above case since we inserted elements in order.

Comment: You need to sort the queue first, since `unique_copy` only deals with consecutive equal elements.

Comment: @jrok: If you need to sort and delete (as stated) you can use a set right away.It has the same complexity

Comment: @jrok: You are creating a lot of sets here (one for every comparison). For small lists this is fine for large size you'll easily run into problems. Set creation is (n log n) where n is the size of the set !!

Comment: @Martin That is not true, there's only one set being constructed here (in the call to `remove_if`). Altough the implementation could copy the predicate around, that's true. I actually posted a Q regarding this, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071553/are-standard-library-algorithms-allowed-to-copy-predicate-arguments

Comment: @jrok I dont think this code that you writen prints the arrays. Can you help me understand why it does?

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Martin answer is probably the best solution. If you cannot change the signature for the function returning a `deque`, you can just construct a [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) from it and all the duplicates will automatically go away:

```
// First you need to declare a compare function for NewArray objects
struct NewArrayComp {
    bool operator()(const NewArray& a1, const NewArray& a2) const {
        return a1.h < a2.h;
    }
};

// Then you can construct a set from the deque
deque<NewArray> dq;
// ...
std::set<NewArray, NewArrayComp> s(dq.begin(), dq.end());

// Finally you can just print the arrays (without duplicates)
for (const auto& a : s)
    PrintBoard(a);
```

This solution has a O(n log n) complexity, while your code is O(n^2).

Additionally, if you do not want to pay the cost of duplicating the elements from the `deque` into the `set` you can use move semantics in C++11:

```
std::set<NewArray, NewArrayComp> s;
std::move(dq.begin(), dq.end(), std::inserter(s, s.begin()));
```

This will just move all the elements without making copies of them.

Comment: I dont want to print all the values of the deque. I want to print only the first ones that have h value equal to 1, 2,3,4,5...ect...ect

Comment: @georgemano The code in my solution will do exactly that. By converting the deque into a set, you are getting rid of duplicated arrays (arrays with same `h` value).

Comment: Can you tell me what the compare function does and why you implement it this way? I dont care alot about erasing the elements. I care alot to print them.

Comment: `set` needs a compare function object (if not using a basic type, such as integer, float, etc.). `NewArrayComp` allows `set` to decide whether two `NewArray` instances are the equivalent or not. That, in your case, is based on the `h` value. Still, you only need to provide a function object that determines whether one `NewArray` instance is less than another instance. Have a look at the [`set` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) and the documentation for a comparison function present in the STL ([less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)).

Comment: Two NewArray structs may have the same h with different arrays.

Comment: But you only want print a `NewArray` for each different `h` value, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12664/discussion-between-betabandido-and-george-mano)

Comment: The code compiles succesfully, but does not print the right arrays.

Comment: @georgemano What do you exactly mean? Arrays with same h value are printed, or the order is not correct. Probably, you can add your new code to this question (just add it at the bottom) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: the arrays that are printed have an increased h.(this is correct). But the printed arrays are not the first he finds. As I said yesterday. I need to print, for example, the first array with h=6 that is closer to MyDeque.begin().

Comment: @georgemano That is strange... I tried it yesterday and it was only inserting the closest ones to the beginning. It might be an issue with VS 2010. GCC does what I expected. Anyway, just try to construct the set in a slightly different way, use: std::set<NewArray, NewArrayComp> s; for (deque<NewArray>::iterator it = dq.begin(); it != dq.end(); ++it) s.insert(*it);