# Are Standard Library algorithms allowed to copy predicate arguments?

Tags: c++, g++, functor, stl-algorithm

Suppose we'd like to remove duplicate values from a vector of `int`s. The usual solution is to sort the vector and erase duplicates with erase-remove idiom. But we need to mantain the order of the elements that will not be removed, so we can't sort. So one might come up with a predicate like this and use with with `remove_if` algorithm:

```
struct comp {
    std::set<int> s;
    comp() : s() {}
    bool operator()(int i)
    {
        return !(s.insert(i)).second;
    }
};
```

But this will break if predicate object will be copied for some reason, since we'll get two copies of the `set` member. And indeed, the gcc's implementation of `remove_if` does exactly that:

```
template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Predicate>
    _ForwardIterator
    remove_if(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
          _Predicate __pred)
    {

      __first = _GLIBCXX_STD_A::find_if(__first, __last, __pred);

      if(__first == __last)                             // ^^^^^ here a copy is made
        return __first;
      _ForwardIterator __result = __first;
      ++__first;
      for(; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if(!bool(__pred(*__first)))
          {
            *__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
            ++__result;
          }
      return __result;
    }
```

The workaround is to make `set` member of our functor static:

```
struct comp {
    static set<int> s;
    comp() { s. clear(); }
    bool operator()(int i)
    {
        return !(s.insert(i)).second;
    }
};
set<int> comp::s;
```

But the question remains:

**Do we need to make sure a possible copy of predicate functor will not break our logic?**
Is there anything in the standard that mandates (or prohibits) certain behaviour with regard to this issue? Or is it a bug in the implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the standard does not specify how many times the predicate will be copied, nor does it say in what order the predicate will be applied to elements of the container.  Essentially, predicates must act like [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function); they must have no observable state.<sup>1</sup>

So `remove_if` does not sound like an appropriate algorithm here.  Hacks such as storing the `set` externally to the functor will not solve the problem; you'll still be invoking undefined behaviour.

---

<sub>1. For a more in-depth discussion, see Item 39 ("*Make predicates pure functions*") of Scott Meyers' [*Effective STL*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-STL-Specific-Professional-Computing/dp/0201749629/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1339941634&sr=8-1).</sub>

Comment: There are algorithms for which standard specifies the order. like `std::copy`, no? And what's with the `Remark: stable` in standard, doesn't that mandate the order is preserved?

Comment: @jrok: It's stable only in the sense that the relative order of preserved elements does not change, not in the sense that the OP wishes.  (And `copy` doesn't take a predicate; `copy_if` does take one, but doesn't specify the order in which it's applied.)

Comment: Meanwhile I found the relevant section about copying predicates in the standard (25.1.10), but can't seem to find anything about predicates not being allowed to preserve state (not that I don't believe you or Scott Meyers - the book is on my todo list for sure :))

Comment: @jrok predicates are allowed to keep mutable state. It is just that this might get you into trouble, specially if you use that state to determine what to return during a call. A predicate should return the same for the same inputs, but the standard isn't going to stop you from doing otherwise.

Comment: I can see the logic behind this. Thanks everyobody (It wasn't me giving -1's, just btw)

Comment: Note, however, that some algorithms do sort-of directly imply support for predicates that hold state. For example, `for_each` returns (a copy of) the functor you passed in, which is useful almost exclusively if the functor maintains some state you can retrieve after applying it to the collection.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: That's true.  But `for_each` doesn't call its argument "predicate".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: True -- the standard doesn't -- but quite a few other people do (to be honest, that probably includes me, at least once in a while).

Comment: While the order of calls to the predicate is not defined for  `remove_copy_if`, it is implied by the other constraints on the algorithm: the output is stored through an `OutputIterator` (can only be incremented, no decrements or random access), the result is *stable* (an implementation cannot start testing from the end, given that it can only write in a forward pass) and at most N executions of the predicate, which implies that the algorithm must be performed in a single pass. Unless I am missing something, the previous requirements do force an order on the execution of the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

> Do we need to make sure a possible copy of predicate functor will not break our logic?

Yes, you should assume the predicates are copied. In C++11, you could consider using [std::ref or std::cref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

<strike>An alternative would be to modify your `comp` structure to take a `set` by reference:</strike>

```
struct comp {
    std::set<int>& s;
    comp(std::set<int> s) : s(s) {}
    bool operator()(int i)
    {
        return !(s.insert(i)).second;
    }
};
```

**Note**: I am not making any statement on whether this would work with `remove_if`, I am simply addressing the issue of copied predicates containing state that should not be copied.

**Edit** As pointed out in comments, the approach is fundamentally broken. The result of the predicate call should not depend on mutable state.

Comment: I believe the results of this are still not well-defined; the standard does not impose an order that `remove_if` must apply the predicate to the container elements.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I wasn't even considering `remove_if`, just dealing with the copied predicates issue. I will clarify my answer.

Comment: It's all part of the same problem.  Predicates must act as if they are  [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you're completely right. I hadn't even realised the predicate call was modifying the set and returning based on that mutating operation.

Comment: It is broken for `remove_if`, other algorithms specify in which order they are apply to arguments making them suited for a mutable predicate.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: `for_each` ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I think the key with `for_each` is that its argument (in the standard) is simply called `Function`, unlike e.g. `remove_if` where it's called `Predicate`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are allowed to copy the arguments an indeterminate number of times. A better approach than making the member set static would be to create the set outside of the functor and pass it as a constructor parameter. Internally store a pointer.

Comment: I believe the results of this are still not well-defined; the standard does not impose an order that `remove_if` must apply the predicate to the container elements.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: true, however since the Standard specifies that it is applicable on Forward Iterators, most implementations will actually apply it in order for efficiency reasons. Sometimes I wonder if this should be explicitly required in the Standard, the problem of the Standard imposing less guarantees that what is typically proposed is that people end up relying (often without realizing it) on those implementation-dependent guarantees.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Besides what Matthieu already mentioned, it is even more important that the result is stored in an `OutputIterator` (i.e. it cannot backtrack) and the number of executions of the predicate is exactly the size of the container. It would be impossible to implement in any other fashion than a forward loop testing each element and deciding there whether to copy or not.